# When do we need to apply a software development methodology?

Tags: development-methodologies

There are many software development methodologies - SCRUM, agile, XP, etc. - and they all have there advantages and disadvantages I suppose.

But when do we really need to apply them? Surely they are not necessary for small 1-man projects, but for large 50+ teams you can most certainly not go about ad-hoc:ing the whole thing.

So what's the line for when to use and when to not use such a methodology, if there indeed is one?

Comment: Ummm...Always??

Answer (score 10):

Even in a strictly 1-man project (you coding software for yourself with no schedule) you have to:

1. Figure out what you actually want/need.
2. Figure out how it can be done (various approaches).
3. Implement it.
4. See what you got and go back to 1), refining the requirements.

You could do it informally (cowboy), but given that the 1-man project is a special edge case (usually there's at least you and someone else you're working for), doing it with some well founded light formalism is virtually always preferable. Keep in mind that the core of the [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) is really just a few principles. The formal methodologies (e.g. Scrum) aimed to reach those principles can and should be tailored according to the team size etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Always

"no methodology" is still a methodology, just not a very good (repeatable, predictable, improvable) one

Answer (score 1):

The question really doesn't make sense. No matter what you do you are applying some form of SDLC approach. That approach might be cowboy coding or waterfall, but it is an approach. A better question is what projects and team sizes are better suited to what approaches.

Comment: What I was aiming for was, when can we no longer rely on cowboy coding. Does that make more sense? If so I'll revise the question.

Comment: Please no waterfall...

Answer (score 1):

Software methodologies are purely a means to reduce project risk.

It's fairly well known that if you take a team of developers practising some methodology and tell them they don't have to follow it anymore and can work however they want, their productivity will increase, but the risk that they will build the wrong thing at the wrong price in the wrong amount of time will greatly increase.

Thus in order to choose an appropriate methodology you first need to determine what the risks are if the project fails.

If the only thing to lose is a couple of weeks of your evenings then a few sketches in a note book and no measurement of progress or deliverables is fine.

If the lives of seven astronauts and billions of dollars is the price of software failure then you better have world class planning, development process, project management and testing in place.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to the development you take must maximise the ROI of the project. Depending on the project nature and the resources available the right direction to take may be different.

There are two obvious rules though, common to designing any functioning system

- the performance and delivarables must
  be quantatively measurable, metrics
  must be as simpe and as unambiguous
  as possible. (reflecting Graham Lee's comment:) As it is not always possible to set up adequate metrics at the very beginning, metrics should evolve as project goes on to reflect the growing expertise of the manangement in the problem domain
- the risks assessement
  procedures (partially based on above
  metrics) must be set up before the
  project starts, and dynamically
  updated as project evolves. The
  mitigation plan must exist for every
  type of identified potential risk and
  shoud be triggered accordingly

The need in asource code version control, system backups, QA procedures, and many other essential bits is just another part of the project risk management.

One more consideration -- the bigger the company is and the more the departments like yours are the more desired it is to have some converged practices used globally to ensure minimum overhead on relocating resources from project to project and also minimum overhead on senior management required to understand the details of projects in departments they run.

Comment: I disagree. If you're starting at cowboy coding, then you must be able to define the processes you currently perform, internalise them, measure them and identify deficiencies before you can work to "maximise the ROI of the project". That's the kind of progression identified in models like CMMI.

Comment: @Graham Lee - The one and the only reason why projects ever start is a profit (or ROI maximisation). The profit must be measurable and risk protected (or, in other words, predictable). The details (like the formal process definitions, particular management practices and so on) are consequences of the above requirement.

Comment: @bobah: there are plenty of open source developers that disagree over the motivation for initiating software projects. But even in the commercial world, a project can be successful without a maximally-efficient project management system. The processes merely need to be good enough not to drag the project into the red. I've worked at companies that had processes with significant overhead, but were not at a mature enough state for changing the process to be achievable/desirable/possible.

Comment: @Graham Lee - please treat my statements more generally, the profit is not necessarily cash income. A project, not generating measurable value (being cash, knowledge, expertise, brand promotion within a community, etc.) is worthless and can't be called a project.

Comment: Right, even so, my disagreements stand: you cannot reliably maximise income of any currency, knowledge or other commodity until you have the ability to measure the effect your work has on your holding of that commodity. Someone who is at the outset of defining their processes isn't in a position to make those measurements effectively.

Comment: @Graham Lee - this is a fair point, I have updated the part of the answer about metrics to reflect this.

Comment: There are other reasons to start a project behind ROI. In the research world, for example, projects are very often started with no ROI in mind, because it's not a relevant metric. In the open source, collaborative, bazaar-inspired world, projects are very often started just for fun, again with no ROI in mind.

Comment: @CesarGon - I'm not sure you understand the abstract meanings of words "return" and "investment". "Fun" is a return, "fame" and "respect" are "return" as well. Time is an investment, weekend time too. For a person with motivated behavior (which all sane people are) there can't be other reason for doing whatever than ROI.

Comment: @bobah: I do understand, yes. My point is that ROI (in that abstract sense) in often not even considered (let alone measured) in some settings, such as research or some open source communities. In order for ROI to be relevant (and your answer to be meaningful to me), you need to (a) define what your "returns" will be; (b) define what your "investments" will be; (c) estimate your ROI based on those returns and investments before the project starts; and (d) measure ROI during and after the project. My experience shows that this is not done *at all* in many occasions.

Comment: @CesarGon - Every research project I know about has a well defined and measurable target (=return). If you have no target you can't call your project a research. If you do have a target, then you have to have a measurable evidence to prove that the project converges to its target (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method for details). I'd appreciate if you could give an example of a successful project where ROI wasn't taken into account and success wasn't tracked _before_ you state that my answer makes no sense.

Comment: @bobah: I am not discussing research projects, but software developed in the context of the research process. Non-finalist experimentation (with no ROI in mind whatsoever) is quite common in my experience in this realm, and definitely encouraged by management. You're welcome to visit our lab (www.iegps.csic.es/lapa) at any time and see for yourself.

Comment: @CesarGon - precisely about software, please check the first sentence on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development. Now about your lab, on the page http://www.iegps.csic.es/lapa/Investigacion_EN.htm the description of every project starts with "The objective of this sub-line is" which is the expected return. The selection criteria for the projects to stay in strategic list is precisely the expected ROI of the project. You can confirm with your management regarding that. The process is same in all research organizations.

Comment: continued -> And back to software, can you give an example of the project which is conducted for one of these research topics but with no ROI (=justification)?

Comment: @bobah: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I am not discussing research projects when I say that software is developed witohout ROI in mind. What I am dicussing is software development efforts that take place within the overall research process, orthogonally to any projects that may be taking place. What you argue is correct for research projects, but not for software efforts that take place within the research process. The two levels of practice are extremely different.

Comment: @CesarGon - not sure what you mean by _software effort_, but any bit of coding should be justified (unless it's a trivial case with a known expected positive outcome or just a learning)

Comment: @bobah: You say that "any bit of coding should be justified". I agree, but the justification doesn't need to be in terms of ROI. In a research context, where software experimentation is an integral part of what you are supposed to do, the justification is not posed in terms of returns and investments, but in terms of exploration, knowledge clarification, etc. I think you may be applying a business mentality to software, but software is created and used in places other than businesses. Have you ever developed at a research lab? Or just for fun? :-)

Comment: @CesarGon - Justification = analysis of what is going to be spent vs what is expected outcome = ROI. Coding for fun = learning or maintaining yourself fluent in technology. Research is not different from business (I know what research is:), if you get result quicker with paper and calculator, you don't write software. If you study the possibility of solving particular problem using computer software, you do write it even if simple physical experiment is cheaper gives immediate answer.

Comment: @bobah: I give up. :-)

Comment: @CesarGon - :-)